# Network Store Interface Service taking up more than 35% of CPU

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, dell-inspiron

I recently updated to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. Now, as soon as I log into the computer, WMIProviderHost takes up a lot of CPU.

I tried all sorts of methods like opening Event Viewer and finding out which services are causing errors, but I couldn't find any of the service's PID in Task Manager, so I did some troubleshooting and found out that if I disable NSI, WMIProviderHost doesn't take up that much of CPU, but if I disable NSI, I can't use WiFi.

I have updated drivers for all the networking devices.

So, is there a way to have WiFi with NSI disabled or is there any other way to make WMIProviderHost take up less CPU?

Laptop specs:

```
DELL Inspiron 15 3521
CPU : Core i5-3337U
RAM : 6 GB
HDD : 500GB 5400RPM
```

[image]

Comment: What is NSI and how is it disabled?

Comment: NSI stands for Network Store Interface Service, you can disable it at startup by using msconfig.

Comment: Have you tried to restart the WMI Provider Host Service?

Comment: Yep, didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps something went wrong with the upgrade. Try maybe a [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html), same effect as a Windows version update, to set all components to a known state.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked.

Comment: I added an answer which you may accept it (tick the V sign next to the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that fixed the problem:

Not all upgrades to Windows 10 finish smoothly.
Sometimes some components are not fully updated or some old settings are left over.

To set everything to a known state, it might be necessary to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

This operation is equivalent to installing a major update to Windows 10,
so the same precautions are required before starting.